# SMB/CIFS/SAMBA: Trying to mount Windows Shares as Read/Write

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab

I realize this question is asked a lot, however, none of the threads I have read have fixed the issue.

Ubuntu: 16.10
Windows: 10

Both are up to date with their auto update features.

I have two directories (Audio, Visual) that are shared on the Windows 10 box. They have read/write permissions for Everyone on the directories, sub-directories, and files. I am able to access the Windows box from other Windows machines and from a Macbook without difficulty.

I can mount the directories with my fstab, they are visible and navigable.

```
//192.168.0.10/Visual /media/Visual cifs credentials=/home/nexist/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noperm 0 0
//192.168.0.10/Audio /media/Audio cifs credentials=/home/nexist/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noperm 0 0
```

Various articles, posts, and threads have caused me to add to my smb.conf file:

```
[audioshare]
path = /media/Audio
writeable = yes

[visualshare]
path = /media/Visual
writeable = yes
```

This is starting to drive me nuts...

Just to clarify, the Windows box is the machine with the directories I wish to access from the Linux box, and they are not writable.

mount command output

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8130048k,nr_inodes=2032512,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1630360k,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1630360k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,gid=46,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
//192.168.0.10/Visual on /media/Visual type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,cache=strict,username=nexist,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.10,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,noperm,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
//192.168.0.10/Audio on /media/Audio type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,cache=strict,username=nexist,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.10,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,noperm,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

Comment: I'm confused, you are trying to mount shares from your win10 box on your linux computer? What does that have to do with samba? Witch is for sharing folders from a linux box to windows clients. Am I getting this correctly? And if I am right, can you access them from "network" in the file-manager?

Comment: The Windows box has the directories I wish to access from Linux.

Comment: And the problem is the network shares aren't writable? This isn't clear in your question. Assuming it is and considering they are in a Windows file server, **it's there you should be checking permissions, not at the client**. Editing smb.conf is for settings pertaining to your **local** shares. It seems you misunderstood whatever "articles, posts and threads". Now please edit your question and explicitly describe what the problem is. As of now it seems your question is **off-topic** and perhaps you should read this: http://www.geeksquad.co.uk/articles/how-to-set-up-file-sharing-on-windows-10

Comment: I've already checked them, hence the statement that they have Read write for Everyone (a windows sharing category). Since he problem is on the Linux side, I am unsure why you say this is off topic.

Comment: Forget smb.conf, it has nothing to do with what you are trying to achieve. You say you can mount and navigate, after you mount, please provide output of mount command, no parameters.

Comment: It's too long for a comment, so I will put it in the main text

Comment: This is a combined Windows - Ubuntu problem: both users on both machines must be named correctly, SIDS need to be mapped correctly, ...  Off-topic here but better on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu

Comment: If you say so, I did manage to brute force the solution by changing the permissions of the /media to 777,  along with the two mount points.

I can now write, but it isn't elegant and it should be possible in some other way, one that doesn't involve changing the permissions of root level directories.

Comment: @fabby The Answer is to add **_netdev** to the line in the fstab. This will cause it to wait for the network and thus mount it properly. I also added a uid as well.

Comment: @NexistXenda'ths  If you have an answer to this question, why not write it out in the answer box so that others with this problem can find it. Comments can be deleted for various reasons. and Answers attract votes that can increase your [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/reputation)

Comment: @NexistXenda'ths: I agree with above.  Just go to the box below and answer your own question!  If you leave a comment here afterwards, I'll come back and upvote!  **;-)**

Comment: @ElderGeek Since I was unaware of that functionality, I hadn't done it. That has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to add a _netdev to the fstab line

```
//192.168.0.10/Visual /media/Visual cifs credentials=/home/nexist/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noperm,_netdev 0 0
```

Comment: Bolding doesn't work in code so I edited your answer to change `**_netdev**` to _netdev  if this is inaccurate please roll back the edit.

Comment: @Fabby, It is done.